# Не запускается handler в ansible playbook'е

Tags: linux, gitlab, ansible, handlers, ansible-playbook

Не запускается handler, хотя ранее, когда я только создал начальный вариант плейбука он отрабатывал. Вот лог, когда работал:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [host] => {}

RUNNING HANDLER [print status] *************************************************
ok: [host] => {"ansible_facts": {"get_status_files": true, "status_info": "success"}, "changed": false}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host            : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

А вот лог, когда уже не работал:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [host] => {}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host            : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

А вот сам плейбук (основная часть):

```yaml
---
- name : This playbook will testing SYNCH & RELOAD probes
  hosts : "{{RUN_HOSTS}}"

  vars :   
    test_source : "{{ SOURCE }}"

    test_dest : "{{ DEST }}"

    need_to_reload_probe : false

    probe_reload : false

  tasks :
    - name : sync lookup_files on {{ RUN_HOSTS }} FOR TEST with probe-reload if it need

      synchronize : 

        src: "{{ test_source }}" 

        dest: "{{ test_dest }}"
      notify: reload probe
      register : sync_rez
      ignore_errors : true

    - name : run handlers

      meta : flush_handlers

    - name : run probe reload script in /tmp
      block :
        - name : probe reload and check if OK

          shell : "bash /tmp/probereload.sh"

          register: HTTP_Server_returned

          when : need_to_reload_probe == true
          ignore_errors : true

        - name : PRINT HTTP_Server_returned
          debug : var=HTTP_Server_returned

          when : HTTP_Server_returned.changed == true

  handlers :
    - name : reload probe
      set_fact :                        
        need_to_reload_probe : true
    - debug : msg=" ---- RUN handler RELOAD - print status ---- "
```

Comment: Так это, у тебя идёт сначала "нотифай", а потом "флаш хэндлерс".

Comment: notify - сначала уведомляет, чтобы хэндлер выполнялся в случае успеха, а flush_handlers - выполняет все уведомлённые хэндлеры конкретно в указанном месте, иначе они по умолчанию выполнятся после всех джобов в самом конце.

Comment: Добавь пожалуйста переменных, чтобы я у себя смог запустить это всё через копипаст. Мне лень все вары заполнять руками.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я разобрался в чём дело было. Почитал документацию на оф сайте, парочку статей в инете. Протестировал с другими параметрами и выяснил, что хэндлер отрабатывает только тогда, когда все таски, связанные с ним, выполняются. Например, если у меня есть файл на локальной машине **test_source**   (как в моём плейбуке выше), я добавляю в него инфу или меняю её в нём, после этого синхронизирую с удалённым файлом **test_dest** (то есть дополняю удалённый файл до состояния текущего), то синхронизация пройдёт только в том случае, если исходный файл был изменён. Соответственно и уведомлённый хэндлер **notify: reload prob**, который запускаeт релоад службы будет выполнен, только в том случае, если успешно прошла синхронизация файлов. В другом случае он не будет запускаться.

ps. Мистер Эсторский, лично для Вас ))

> hosts : "localhost"   vars :
> test_source : "/tmp/source/test.file"
>
> ```
> test_dest : "/tmp/dest/test.file"
> ```